# How do I procedurally adjust media queries with pixel accuracy using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have multiple media queries with 20px increments that adjust margin-top by 5-10px to create a fluid height resize effect.

Is there a way to do this in 1-2px increments using javascript or jquery? Below is the code I'm currently using, but I'm curious if this can be done with just a few lines of code in a cleaner fashion to create a more fluid effect.

div ID is `#underslider1`

```
@media (min-width:1000px) and (max-width:1020px) {
#underslider1 { margin-top: 90px !important;}
}

@media (min-width:980px) and (max-width:1000px) {
#underslider1 { margin-top: 85px !important;}
}

@media (min-width:960px) and (max-width:980px) {
#underslider1 { margin-top: 80px !important;}
}

@media (min-width:940px) and (max-width:960px) {
#underslider1 { margin-top: 75px !important;}
}

@media (min-width:920px) and (max-width:940px) {
#underslider1 { margin-top: 70px !important;}
}

@media (min-width:900px) and (max-width:920px) {
#underslider1 { margin-top: 65px !important;}
}

@media (min-width:880px) and (max-width:900px) {
#underslider1 { margin-top: 55px !important;}
}

@media (min-width:860px) and (max-width:880px) {
#underslider1 { margin-top: 45px !important;}
}

@media (min-width:840px) and (max-width:860px) {
#underslider1 { margin-top: 35px !important;}
}

@media (min-width:820px) and (max-width:840px) {
#underslider1 { margin-top: 25px !important;}
}

@media (min-width:790px) and (max-width:820px) {
#underslider1 { margin-top: 10px !important;}
}
```

Comment: Instead of doing this, I'd advise you to look into the reason that causes the top slider to act up. Although you can use JavaScript to achieve what you want (handling the window `resize` event, getting the window's `width` and setting the `margin-top` accordingly), that almost is never the correct approach. It seems to me that you're trying to compensate an error somewhere with a hacky solution.

Comment: may I know the reason for using `media-query` for width range from `1000px to 840px` instead of going with the popular screen size?

Comment: It's not my site, I spent about 5 hours trying to find the issue, and while I discovered it, it would break the other 100 pages on the site. I'm just helping with one page.

Comment: Give them more bugs and chaos.

Comment: @vikscool it's the point at which the entire site margin goes from 40px to 0px, and my next row disappears, until it reappears

Comment: @KoshVery LOL yeah, I just want to get this page working.

Comment: You'd better add a [mcve] here and ask for help with the actual problem.

Comment: @JeremiahSamuelKrakowski identify the screen size at which the **size changes** and do the styling for that only instead of trying to make media query for all the sizes (which will again be a hard task). You can identify the size using `ctrl`+`shift`+`m` for Firefox and chrome (also via `developer-tools`) or you can use the extension [window resizer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/window-resizer/kkelicaakdanhinjdeammmilcgefonfh?hl=en) on chrome.

Comment: There is no pattern in your margin. In some width you're adjusting the `margin-top` by 5, and some by 10, and some by 15. Seems like a handmade fix for the current problem. I think that if it works fine now, you can keep your current solution. A smooth transition during a window resize is hardly necessary.

Comment: @vikscool FYI break points should not follow any popular screen size, they should actually follow your particular content, that's how you efficiently create responsive sites... as for screen sizes there will soon be more than you can count...

Comment: The answer given to me below seems to answer it. I edited my question to be more MCV. @ChanMT it has to do with a slight ratio issue, the margin size increment needed to be larger the smaller it got to adjust for aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't give the exact same results but it may help:

```
@media (min-width: 790px) and (max-width: 1020px) {
    #underslider1 {
        margin-top: calc( 10px + (90 - 10) * ( (100vw - 790px) / ( 1020 - 790) ));
    }
}
```

Comment: This does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the JavaScript API `window.matchMedia` and write all of that programmatically within a loop...

Comment: That's the solution I needed, for some reason it wasn't coming to me.

Comment: @JeremiahSamuelKrakowski How is this different than your css solution?

Comment: @andriusain sorry, im new here! Learning this system. Thanks!

Comment: @ChanMT it could loop through at the proper ratio faster. It's essentially the same solution tho. I would be curious how to account for the fact that the ratio of the needed margin-top increases the smaller the screen gets